# Proving logical equivalence of two statements

Tags: geometry, logic

So for extra credit, our teacher told us to prove the following 2 statements are logically equivalent:

1. The square is the quadrilateral that maximizes the area given a fixed perimeter $P$.
2. The square is the quadrilateral that minimizes the perimeter given a fixed area $A$.

My question is, $\textbf{how would I go about proving this?}$

Here is the proof I offered:

Statement 1 can be reworded as the following:

1. The square is the quadrilateral that maximizes the number $Y=\frac{A}{P}$

Where $A$ is the area and $P$ is the perimeter of the quadrilateral. Similarly, Statement 2 can be reworded as the following:

2. The square is the quadrilateral that minimizes the number $Z=\frac{1}{Y}=\frac{P}{A}$

This means that when Y is maximized, $\frac{1}{Y}$ must be minimized. Let $S$ represent the statement "Quadrilateral S is a square of length $m$ and width $n$." Let $y$ represent "$Y$ is maximized and $z$ represent "$Z$ is minimized." Then statements 1 and 2 are equal to:

1. $S \rightarrow y$
2. $S \rightarrow z$

If we show that $y \equiv z$, then statement 1 is equivalent to statement 2. But then if $Y>\frac{mn}{2m+2n}$ for all $m$ and $n$ such that $m\neq n$, it follows that $\frac{1}{Y}<\frac{2m+2n}{mn}$ for all $m$ and $n$ such that $m\neq n$. Since statement $y$ and statement $z$ imply each other, it follows that statement 1 and statement 2 are logically equivalent.

But of course I get it wrong, since when I reworded the statements I forgot that the area in statement 1 is a variable while in statement 2 it is a constant, and vice versa for the perimeter. I'm kind of stuck at the moment, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what class this is for? I want to gauge what sort of tools you'd want to use to write this proof

Comment: This is actually just a BC Calculus class where these two statements were problems in our textbook we had to prove using typical max/min strategies.

Comment: Ah okay; I was about to throw some real analysis at this problem. I'll tinker with it and see if a calculus solution pops out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that two statements, $S$ and $T$, are logically equivalent by proving that $S \Rightarrow T$ and $T \Rightarrow S$.

I'll show one direction, and you should be able to figure out the other:

Given "The square is the quadrilateral that maximizes the area given a fixed perimeter $P$.", prove "The square is the quadrilateral that minimizes the perimeter given a fixed area $A$."

Consider all quadrilaterals with the same fixed area $A$. There should be one (or more) quadrilaterals with the minimum perimeter. Take any one such quadrilateral, call it $Q$.

If $Q$ is NOT a square, then by the given statement, we can construct a square $Q^\prime$ which has the same perimeter as $Q$, but with larger area $A^\prime > A$. Furthermore, we can simply "shrink" $Q^\prime$ by an appropriate scaling factor to get a square, $Q^{\prime\prime}$ with area $A$. Since $Q^{\prime\prime}$ is smaller than $Q^\prime$, it must have a smaller perimeter. We have reached a contradiction, so our initial assumption that $Q$ is not a square is false.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

I will hint a way to the first one and leave the rest to you:

[image]

- Perimeter $C=2A+2B$ (whatever the lengths of $A$, $B$, Right?)
- Area $D=A*B$ (whatever the lengths of $A$, $B$, Right?)

Now let's translate the problem to a $MAX, MIN$ problem, we can say in other words :

Prove that $Max(A*B)$ is when $A=B$, knowing that $A+B=Constant=C$ ?

OK? let's tackle this one now :

$A+B=C$ ==> $B=C-A$

$D=A*B$

$D=A(C-A)$

$D=-A^2+CA$ (we want to compute the maximum of $D$ with $A$ as a variable)

I think the easiest way is to see its first derivative

$D'=-2A+C$:

$D'=0$==> $A=\frac{C}{2}$ (Note that this is the maximum of $D$)

$A=\frac{C}{2}$ ==> $B=C-A=C-\frac{C}{2}=\frac{C}{2}$ (Great!)

So we proved that: in order the area of quadrilateral to be the max, the sides should be equal, knowing that the perimeter is constant.

I leave the other part as an exercise.

Comment: The question asks to prove the two statements are equivalent, not that they must be true.

Comment: opss! thankS @user137794 I didn't notice! I will try to wrap my answer to match the query, quite sure it won't get too far though